# Import data from one workbook to another within a date range

Tags: excel, vba

I open my workbook (ThisWorkbook) and by clicking a button can browse and select another workbook (OpenBook) and import data from a sheet (Report Data).

Column I in the Report Data sheet contains a  beginning date and Column J contains an ending date for each period (usually a month).

In ThisWorkbook I  have a tab called "Instructions" I want to allow the user to input in this tab a beg. date (cell C8) and ending date (E8) the code will then reference these dates and only import data within that range.

From my research its appears you need to use Autofilter and then copy the visible rows. But I can't get it to work.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
  Dim FileToOpen As Variant
  Dim OpenBook As Workbook
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your ADR file & import range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
  If FileToOpen <> False Then
     Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
     OpenBook.Worksheets("Report Data").Range("A9:MJ128").Copy
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Data").Range("A9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Data").Range("A9").PasteSpecial xlFormats
      OpenBook.Close False

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you set `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` at end (vs. False). Also, are you trying to copy all columns (A:M) and to where? First avilable row on report data?

Comment: A9: MJ128 is copied from OpenBook and pasted into ThisWorkbook starting at A9.  I have the import data working fine I just want to copy and paste only data within a custom date range. Right now it just copy and paste everything in A9:MJ128.

Comment: So after you copy everything, you want to then test if the copied values match the user inputs, or do you want to test for that after? If you loop through the column and test if the values are within the range, and then copy, you should be good.

Comment: So for example in ThisWorkbook A9:MJ128 is a set of data with dates in Col I & J. The way it works now everything is simply copy and pasted. I want the user to put a beg. date 01/01/2016 and ending date 01/30/2016 and only data within that date will be copy and pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to replicate your situation with all the various file names, however I think this should work. The key part of the code is the loop  with the `aCell` rows and testing if the two columns meet the predefined conditions in variables `begDate` and `EndDate`. If they match, then simply insert values (no need to copy paste), into the sheet row. There's a counter `k` that will ensure the macro doesn't overwrite its own members (for that procedure only).

While I haven't tested this, ultimately it's a pretty simple test of items, so if you get errors, double check that your variables are correct by stepping through your code.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
  Dim FileToOpen As Variant
  Dim OpenBook As Workbook, openSheet As Worksheet, iSheet As Worksheet, pSheet As Worksheet
  
  'worksheets
  Set iSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions")
  Set pSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Data")
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your ADR file & import range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

    Dim begDate As Date, endDate As Date
  
    begDate = iSheet.Range("C8").Value
    endDate = iSheet.Range("E8").Value
    
  
  
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set openSheet = OpenBook.Worksheets("Report Data")
    
    Dim aCell As Range, k As Long
    For Each aCell In Intersect(openSheet.UsedRange, openSheet.Range("I:I")).Cells
        'loops through rows testing if column i is >= than begdate and column j is <= endDate
        If aCell >= begDate And aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <= endDate Then
             'when match is found, value is inserted directly to sheet
             pSheet.Range("A9").Offset(k, 0).Value = Intersect(aCell.EntireRow, aCell.Worksheet.Range("A:M")).Value
            'offset will ensure data is no overwritten.
             k = k + 1
        End If
    Next aCell
    OpenBook.Close False

End If
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Everything works great, however, it only copies the data within the dates for first column (A).  If I change A9 for B9 then it pastes in the values from B and so forth.  Do I need to add this code over and over again for A through MJ?

Comment: Ok I go it. It should be pSheet.Range("A9:MJ9"). This imports everything.